# MegaMenu in ReactJs using useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I am trying to achieve a mega menu in my react project. Find the sample design below. In ReactJS I am trying to toggle the menu onclick but when I am clicking on one of the li the State is applying on others and the class is applying to every li children. Please find the code below the SS

[image: Example design of my mega menu.]

***Initializing State.***

```
  const [mainMenu, setMainMenu] = useState(false);
  const handleMainMenu = () => {
    setMainMenu(!mainMenu);
  };
```

***Setting State onClick of parent element***

`onClick={handleMainMenu}`

***Adding class on change of state***

```
${mainMenu ? "nb-block" : "nb-hidden"}
```

Comment: Why do you have a dollar sign here: `${mainMenu ? "nb-block" : "nb-hidden"}`? Sorry, kind of hard to troubleshoot without seeing the full context.

Comment: @codemonkey I'd guess that's embedded in the middle of a template string, as in `className={\`button ${mainMenu ? "nb-block" : "nb-hidden"}\`}` @himanshuJain We really need to see more to be able to help. Too many gaps are missing.

Comment: @NicholasTower Ah... that would make sense.

Comment: Please find the pastebin link of the component. https://pastebin.com/mJtADnNV